# Inner join without results from second table

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to create an inner-join MySQL Query of two tables:

```
'swatchset' 
->swatchset_id
->swatchset_name

'swatches'
->swatch_id
->swatch_name
->swatch_hex
->etc...
```

I currently have one record in the 'swatchset' table:

> swatchset_id | swatchset_name
>
> ```
>      8           default
> ```

The 'swatches' table is empty.

I want to get as result the 'swatchset'.'swatchset_name'
I guess I don't understand INNER JOIN very well because this Query results nothing:

```
    SELECT `swatchset`.`swatchset_name`, `swatches`.`swatch_id`, `swatches`.`swatch_name`, `swatches`.`swatch_hex`, `swatches`.`swatch_type` FROM `swatchset`
    INNER JOIN `swatches`
    ON `swatches`.`f_swatchset_id` = `swatchset`.`swatchset_id`
    WHERE `swatchset`.`swatchset_id` = '8';
```

How can I get at least the found 'swatchset' row as result?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

Left outer join will fill with nulls columns of second table when not found:

```
SELECT `swatchset`.`swatchset_name`, `swatches`.`swatch_id`, `swatches`.`swatch_name`, `swatches`.`swatch_hex`, `swatches`.`swatch_type` FROM `swatchset`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `swatches`
    ON `swatches`.`f_swatchset_id` = `swatchset`.`swatchset_id`
    WHERE `swatchset`.`swatchset_id` = '8';
```

inner join doesn't return entries from first table without matching ones in second table